# Can't enable debug context for QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

I want to enable OpenGL logging in Qt. My code:

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>
#include <QOpenGLContext>
#include <QOpenGLDebugLogger>

QSurfaceFormat createSurfaceFormat() {
    QSurfaceFormat format;

    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);

    return format;
}

void initGLLogging(QQmlApplicationEngine& engine) {
    QOpenGLContext *ctx = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
    QOpenGLDebugLogger *logger = new QOpenGLDebugLogger(&engine);
    logger->initialize();
    qDebug() << "can gl log? " << ctx->hasExtension(QByteArrayLiteral("GL_KHR_debug"));
    QObject::connect(logger, &QOpenGLDebugLogger::messageLogged,
        [&](const QOpenGLDebugMessage &debugMessage) {
            qDebug() << debugMessage;
        }
    );
    logger->startLogging();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(::createSurfaceFormat());

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    ::initGLLogging(engine);

    return app.exec();
}
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
}
```

The output, after building in debug mode and running in the debugger, is:

```
QOpenGLDebugLogger::initialize(): the current context is not a debug context:
    this means that the GL may not generate any debug output at all.
    To avoid this warning, try creating the context with the
    QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext surface format option.
can gl log?  true
```

Any idea why it's failing?

**Note**: I'm using ANGLE-mode in all Qt apps on my system, enabled via an env var, because otherwise they break in all kinds of ways. That's very likely to be related to the problem, but I can't do without this setting.

Comment: Note that there's noone guaranteeing that you have an OpenGL context in the main thread when you use QQmlApplicationEngine. I'd also check ANGLE's source code to check if it honours `EGL_CONTEXT_OPENGL_DEBUG_BIT_KHR`.

Comment: @peppe: I do have an OpenGL context there, though, as evidenced by the `can gl log?  true` in the output. Re: ANGLE's source code, fair point.